# Not able to select value from dropdown experience(Exp.) field of Naukri.com

Tags: selenium

The following code is not working, and is throwing the error shown below:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

driver.get("http://www.naukri.com/");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Select Exp_drpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("expSL")));

Exp_drpdwn.selectByValue("2");
```

### Error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 100.05 seconds
Build info: version: '2.39.0', revision: 'ff23eac', time: '2013-12-16 16:12:12'
System info: host: 'ANUPAM-PC', ip: '192.168.1.39', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
Session ID: 1c82f01f-2f60-43b6-8b70-ce139ee96508
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are trying to select is not visible. It becomes visible upon clicking on **By.id("exp")** node. So try clicking it before accessing the select:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("exp")).click();
```

Alternatively you can edit the value with JavaScript:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('exp').value = 2");
```

Comment: Thnaks for the comment...updated the code as per you suggestion code  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.naukri.com/");
  
  
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  
driver.findElement(By.id("exp")).click();
  
  Select Exp_drpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("expSL")));
  
  Exp_drpdwn.selectByValue("2");

Comment: Please disregard above commment                                                                 @al0:Thanks for the comment...updated the code as per you suggestion code    ..but it is still not working and also got the error ["Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 100.05 seconds"]  
--------
CODE USED
----------  
driver.findElement(By.id("exp")).click();
Select Exp_drpdwn = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("expSL")));
Exp_drpdwn.selectByValue("2");

Comment: Updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: Thanks alternative method is working..it will also be very helpful if you can let me know why the earlier solution did not work.As per my knowledge that solution was also correct.

Comment: It worked for me in Chrome. Not sure what's wrong with Firefox.